# Help repairing a 14.04 (upgrade from 13.10) system installation?

Tags: upgrade

I installed 14.04 by upgrading from 13.10. I've had a few issues, but nothing preventing me from working.

Today, I started having problems with my headset - it no longer showed up in my device listings, and although I could control volume settings from the headset controls, no sound was sent to the headset and the headset's mic was not recognized.

I tried to update the alsa-utils but no update was available although apt-get did mark it for manual processing (thanks) in the future, then I r&r'd pulse audio packages and that's when everything went south.

On reboot, I lost a crapton of stuff - in my System Settings window, I now only have Language Support, Security & Privacy, Printers, Landscape Service, and Software & Updates. Everything else is gone.

I removed the pulse-audio packages I installed previously and rebooted but no change. I updated the available packages with `apt-get` and rebooted - no change.

Since I upgraded from 13.10, I never created an install disk.

Is there a command or set of commands that can validate the 14.04 base install and reload w/e packages went missing without having to do a complete re-install and losing all my files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I ended up removing the packages that I added:

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio paprefs pulseaudio-esound-compat kmix
```

and then I reinstalled the desktop:

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
```

I got all of the system-setting/control panel option back. I rebooted and confirmed that the changes persisted and my environment is back to as it was.

Comment: Really nice to post the solution here. Please also set your answer as solution, so your question will be displayed as answered.